# Openapi 3 - Inheritance & Polimorphism - redoc-cli

Tags: swagger, openapi, redoc

On my openapi yaml file I have a **Layout** schema, which has an attribute **fields**, which is an array of **Field** objects. My idea is to have a parent Field schema with common attributes, and some children schemas (**TextInput**, **Select**, **Toggle**, etc...) which inherit those and extend with their particular attributes.

So, this is what I'm trying:

```
Layout:
  type: object
  properties:
    fields:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/Field'
Field:
  type: object
  properties:
    name:
      type: string
      description: Field name.
    label:
      type: string
      description: Field label.
    description:
      type: string
      description: Short description explaining the purpose of the field.
    fieldType:
      type: string
      description: Field type.
  required:
    - name
    - label
  discriminator: fieldType
  mapping:
    text: '#/TextInput'
    select: '#/Select'
TextInput:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/Field'
    - type: object
      properties:
        placeholder:
          type: string
          description: Field placeholder. **Only for *text* fields.**
Select:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/Field'
    - type: object
      properties:
        options:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
        multiple:
          type: boolean
          default: false
```

Compilation works fine, but when I expand the `fields` attribute I see:

```
Array ()
 Schema not provided
```

I would expect something like what happens here with the `petType` attribute in the 200 response:
http://redocly.github.io/redoc/#operation/findPetsByStatus

Comment: What is the expected result and what do you get instead?

Comment: I'm seeing just an empty white rectangle when expanding fields attribute: https://imgur.com/pi7eWnV. I would expect to see something like "One of" and the redoc buttons for the different concrete schemas, and clicking on each would show the corresponding attributes.

Comment: I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Add title : ObjectName under child schemas then it will display Array(ObjectName) instead of Array().

Try this.
TextInput:
allOf:
- $ref: '#/Field'
- title : TextInput
- type: object
properties:
placeholder:
type: string
description: Field placeholder. **Only for *text* fields.**

See this for reference: https://redoc.ly/docs/resources/discriminator/